# RabbitMQ Consumer Hosted Service - only consumes first batch of messages and needs to be restarted

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using C# and have implemented a BackgroundService running in Linux.
(Credit to https://codeburst.io/get-started-with-rabbitmq-2-consume-messages-using-hosted-service-e7e6a20b15a6 for the guide on writing a Hosted Service).

It seems to consume the first batch of messages only and requires a restart of the service before fetching the next messages that were delivered to the queue since receiving the first batch.  I.e. Start consumer service, send messages, messages are received, send new messages, messages are not received until service is restarted.

Does anyone have any ideas please? Thank you

```
public class ConsumerWorker : BackgroundService
{

    private ConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _channel;
    public ConsumerWorker()
    {
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = "localhost",
            Port = 5672,
            UserName = "User",
            Password = "password",
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true,
        };
        _connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "myqueue",
                                durable: true,
                                exclusive: false,
                                autoDelete: false,
                                arguments: null);
        _channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += async (bc, ea) =>
        {
            var bodyBytes = ea.Body.ToArray();

            _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: "myqueue", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The program.cs:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ConsumerWorker >();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**SOLUTION:**

The issue was this line:
`_channel.BasicConsume(queue: "myqueue", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);`

I changed it to:
`_channel.BasicConsume(queue: "myqueue", autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);` and it is now behaving correctly

Comment: It may be because you are immediately returning from the method ExecuteAsync with the statement : await Task.Complete, Try to await until cancellationToken cancelled and do not exit the method

Comment: @RaminRahimzada Hi, I tried that but it would not work at all if I removed the final await Task.Complete. Have tried removing only the inner Task.Complete also.

Comment: Carefully review your code and compare it with [the example](https://github.com/changhuixu/rabbitmq-labs/blob/master/03_WorkerServiceConsumer/EmailWorker/Worker.cs). You have forgotten to make your `.Received` callback `async`, for one thing.

Comment: @LukeBakken Hi, thank you and so, so sorry, the example I placed was after several attempts at fixing the issue and when I restored it, I missed out the async. I will add it back in the example code provided above and to be sure I have re-tested the behaviour (still persists)

Comment: Your message handler is the `consumer.Received` event hanlder, not `ExecuteAsync`. The way the code is written, it sets up an event hanlder for `consumer ` and then discards both when `ExecuteAsync` exits. You need to save `consumer` in a field along with the other RabbitMQ fields.

Comment: A good idea would be to extract all this code into a separate class, eg `RabbitMqClient`. All the question's code essentially sets up the connection and receiver. The actual message could be processed eg in an `ActionBlock` or more complex Dataflow pipeline, completely separating the message processing from the RabbitMQ setup

Comment: I figured it out! it is the "true" flag in autoack: for the consumer! I thought I needed to set this as true.  I will take on your suggestions thanks @PanagiotisKanavos and separate it out in to a class - do you have any links for example implementations? Many thanks